# Selecting value from list of tuples Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to extract values from list of tuples:

```
s3_headers = %{headers: [{"x-amz-id-2","yQKurzVIApkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFBINsPxe+7Vc="},
  {"x-amz-request-id", "82xxxxxxxxx23"},
  {"Date", "Thu, 25 May 2017 22:03:09 GMT"},
  {"Last-Modified", "Thu, 25 May 2017 21:42:28 GMT"},
  {"ETag", "\"6f04733333333333333368997\""},
  {"x-amz-meta-original_name", "Screenshot from 2016-11-27 17-32-03.png"},
  {"Accept-Ranges", "bytes"}, {"Content-Type", ""},
  {"Content-Length", "612391"}, {"Server", "AmazonS3"}], status_code: 200}
```

The way how I manage to do it so far is like this:

```
{"x-amz-meta-original_name", original_name } = s3_headers |> List.keyfind("x-amz-meta-original_name", 0)
{"Content-Length", content_length }          = s3_headers |> List.keyfind("Content-Length", 0)
{"Content-Type", content_length }            = s3_headers |> List.keyfind("Content-Type", 0)
```

It feels like overcomplication can you recommend better way ?

Comment: I thought `Keyword.get` used to work for this but I just checked it only works for atom keys. I don't think there's any better way to find an item in a list of tuples. You can create a map from this and use pattern matching or bracket notation but I'd just create a wrapper for `List.keyfind` which returns only the found value. See https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/52fbe6da77081a09d17af105946618f008653294/lib/elixir/lib/keyword.ex#L177-L183.

Comment: You could also use `Enum`'s [`find`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3), eg:
```{"x-amz-meta-original_name", original_name} = Enum.find(s3_headers, fn {key, _val} -> key == "x-amz-meta-original_name" end)```.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I usually convert tuple lists with string keys to a Map. Then you access with string keys. This will take a little more time upfront, but much less time of each access than Enum.find

```
iex(19)> headers = Enum.into s3_headers[:headers], %{}
%{"Accept-Ranges" => "bytes", "Content-Length" => "612391",
  "Content-Type" => "", "Date" => "Thu, 25 May 2017 22:03:09 GMT",
  "ETag" => "\"6f04733333333333333368997\"",
  "Last-Modified" => "Thu, 25 May 2017 21:42:28 GMT", "Server" => "AmazonS3",
  "x-amz-id-2" => "yQKurzVIApkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFBINsPxe+7Vc=",
  "x-amz-meta-original_name" => "Screenshot from 2016-11-27 17-32-03.png",
  "x-amz-request-id" => "82xxxxxxxxx23"}
iex(20)> original_name = headers["x-amz-meta-original_name"]
"Screenshot from 2016-11-27 17-32-03.png"
iex(21)> content_length = headers["Content-Length"]
"612391"
```

Comment: worked like a charm, Thank you. I've summarized the discussion to TIL blog http://www.eq8.eu/tils/29-selecting-value-from-list-of-tuples-elixir if anyone interested

Comment: Keep in mind that tuple lists and maps have different characteristics. A tuple list can contain duplicate "keys" while maps can't. It's possible to lose information using this approach.